# REACT: How to render var Component = new Component in return statement?

Tags: reactjs

This is inside Class component (d is reurning date objects, set is settings component)

```
 Maanantai = new DayLayout(d.state.maanantai)
  Tiistai = new DayLayout(d.state.tiistai)
  Keskiviikko = new DayLayout(d.state.keskiviikko)
  Torstai = new DayLayout(d.state.torstai)
  Perjantai = new DayLayout(d.state.perjantai)
  Lauantai = new DayLayout(d.state.lauantai)
  Sunnuntai = new DayLayout(d.state.sunnuntai)
  set = new Settings

  return (
    <div>
      <div><h3>Otsikko palkki</h3></div>
      {(() => {
        if (set.getWeekstart != "Maanantai") {
          return (
            <Sunnuntai/>
          )
        }
      })()}
      <Maanantai/>
      <Tiistai/>
      <keskiviikko/>
      <Torstai/>
      <Perjantai/>
      <Lauantai/>
      {(() => {
        if (set.getWeekstart == "Maanantai") {
          return (
            <Sunnuntai/>
          )
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
```

I am trying to render multiple week day tables. How ever VisualStudio code displayis errors in this code and ot dont work. Somehow it dont acccept acept new classes as objects, is there way a from and component from class object?

Comment: Show us the code of `DayLayout`. Also in general, it doesn't make sense to me that initializing a class will return a working component. Why not create a component that accepts the argument in the `DayLayout` constructor as props, and have it work as a normal component that does whatever it needs there. Why do you need to generate a component through class initialization? That is not the correct approach

Comment: Oh yes I can pass directly the probs to DayLayout without intialising new classes thans for reply Im coming from C and C++ and there we do it this way.

Comment: But if I try adding probs it again have problem of not putting code to blue and underline red how ever Im using <DayLayout day={d.state.maanantai} it gives errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working, thax all reposponses, they were very helpfull:

```
import React from "react";
import DayLayout from "./komponentit/day";
import Settings from "./settings"
import Dates from "./komponentit/dates";

var n = new date();
var d = new Dates(n)
//Eli daylayout tarvii tietää milloinkin aktiivisen viikon
//pitää hakea pvm atlasianiasta tai hakea nykyinen viikk
set = new Settings

class ViikkoLayout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Projektit: '',
    Tasks: '',
    pvm: '',
    date: '',
    week: ''

  };
  /*const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columns);*/
  // Pitää editoida tähän asetusten mukainen muutos onko MA vai SU ekapaiva

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Otsikko palkki</h3>
        {set.getWeekstart != "Maanantai" && <DayLayout day={...d.state.sunnuntai}/> }
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.maanantai}/>
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.tiistai}/>
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.keskiviikko}/>
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.torstai}/>
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.perjantai}/>
        <DayLayout day={...d.state.lauantai}/>
        {set.getWeekstart == "Maanantai" && <DayLayout day={...d.state.sunnuntai}/> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ViikkoLayout;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
{(() => {
        if (set.getWeekstart != "Maanantai") {
          return (
            <Sunnuntai/>
          )
        }
      })()}
```

use this

```
{set.getWeekstart != "Maanantai" && <Sunnuntai/> }
```

or

```
{set.getWeekstart != "Maanantai" ? <Sunnuntai/>  : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some approaches you can try

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {

  // if you dont want new Settings() to be called on every render
  const settings = useMemo(() => {
  
     return new Settings()

  }, []) // dependencies for settings or just move settings out of the component

  const Tiistai = useMemo(() => {
      // if you need to construct the component in a specific way
      // const propsCreator = new DayLayout(d.state.tiistai)
      // return (props) => <RenderComponent {...props} {...propsCreator.getProps() } />
      return (props) => <DayLayout {...props} state={d.state.tiistai} />

  }, [d.state.tiistai]) 
  

  return (
     ...
     // approach one
     <Maanantai state={d.state.maanantai} />
    // approach two
    <Tiistai/>
    ...
  )

}
```

Hope it helps you in some way